# Considers the wrong instance - DIETs

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a script to represent positive integers by a discrete interval encoding tree (diet) following [this](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/papers/Diet_JFP98.pdf) article and I'm currently running tests (with *unittest*).

```
class node:
    def __init__(self,n_Left=None,n_Right=None,LeftChild_=None,RightChild_=None):
      self.interval=[min(n_Left,n_Right),max(n_Left,n_Right)]
      self.RightChild=RightChild_
      self.LeftChild=LeftChild_
    def length(self):
        if (self.interval,self.LeftChild,self.RightChild)==([None,None],None,None):
            raise EmptyNode()
        return self.interval[1]-self.interval[0]+1


class diet:
    def __init__(self,root_=None):
        self.root=root_

    def member(self,saught_value):
        node_=self.root #a node instance
        if node_==None: return False
        if (saught_value>=(node_.interval)[0]) and (saught_value<=(node_.interval)[1]):
            return True
        if saught_value<(node_.interval)[0]:
            L=diet(node_.LeftChild)
            return L.member(saught_value)
        R=diet(node_.RightChild)
        return R.member(saught_value)

    def append(self,value):
        if self.member(value):
            return self
        node_=self.root
        if node_==None:
            return diet(node(value,value))
        right_child=node_.RightChild
        left_child=node_.LeftChild
        if value<(node_.interval)[0] :
          if value+1==(node_.interval)[0] :
            Root=node(value,(node_.interval)[1],left_child,right_child)
            return joinLeft(diet(Root))
          else:
            subtree=diet(left_child) 
            Root=node((node_.interval)[0],(node_.interval)[1],subtree.append(value),right_child)
            return diet(Root)
        if value >(node_.interval)[1]:
          if value==(node_.interval)[1]+1:
            Root=node((node_.interval)[0],value,left_child,right_child)
            return joinRight(diet(Root))
          else:
            subtree=diet(right_child  )
            Root=node((node_.interval)[0],(node_.interval)[1],left_child,subtree.append(value))             
            return diet(Root)


#TEST
max_number_of_nodes=20 
maximum=100
minimum=0

class Tests_Cases(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.number_of_nodes=random.randint(0,max_number_of_nodes)
        self.nLeft=random.randint(minimum,maximum)
        self.nRight=random.randint(minimum,maximum)
        self.root=node(self.nLeft,self.nRight)
        self.tree=diet(self.root)
        self.values=[]
        for i in range(max_number_of_nodes-1):
            (self.values).append(random.randint(minimum,maximum))
    def test_member(self):
        x=random.randint(minimum,maximum)
        self.assertFalse(diet().member(x))
        self.assertTrue(((self.tree).member(self.nLeft))&((self.tree).member(self.nRight)))
        for v in self.values:
            self.tree=(self.tree).append(v)
        for v in self.values:
            self.assertTrue((self.tree).member(v))
```

When I run the test, I have an error. Here's the traceback :

```
ERROR: test_member (__main__.Tests_Cases)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 155, in test_member
    self.tree=(self.tree).append(v)
  File "script.py", line 101, in append
    if self.member(value):
  File "script.py", line 96, in member
    return R.member(saught_value)
  File "script.py", line 90, in member
    if (saught_value>=(node_.interval)[0]) and (saught_value<=(node_.interval)[1]):
AttributeError: diet instance has no attribute 'interval'
```

I can't see why by running `R.member(saught_value)` and testing the *if* condition, it considers `node_` as an instance of *diet* : I explicitly put in the first line of `member`'s definition, `node_=self.root` which should be an instance of *node*.

Comment: Apparently, 'should be' != 'is' ;-).  Add debugging code such as `assert isinstance(root_, (type(None), node)` as first line in .__init__ to see if there is a bad constructor call and if so, where (from traceback).

Comment: Well, I've added some prints in the code, and it turned out that after two or three calls to method member, RightChild (respectively LeftChild) in method member is considered to be an instance of diet … I can't find out why.